# Instantiate many React Components with different args

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object representing field names, types, and values:

```
fields = {
  'foo': ['number', null],
  'bar': ['text', null],
  'baz': ['radio', ["Yes", "No"]]
}
```

Is it worth creating a generic Component in React where each input is rendered? Or should I just hard-code the input fields in a single React Component, grouping the fields together?

To prevent this from being opinion based: *Are there any real advantages in using a component for each field instead of just hard-coding the fields in a single component*?